# How to fetch all data in one request in Ember Data?

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data

I am using the ember 1.8.1, ember data 1.0.0-beta 11.
I have two types name A and B the relationship is like

```
A = DS.Model.extend({
   bs: DS.hasMany('B', {async: true})
});
B = DS.Model.extend({
   a: DS.belongsTo('A')
});
```

According this post:
http://thau.me/2014/09/ember-data-mastering-async-relationships/

When I try to fetch the bs in a.model in template like this:
{{#each b in model.bs}}

The ember's RESTAdapter will send a http request like this:
URL/bs?ids[]=1&ids[]=2

But it will send several request like this:
URL/b/1
URL/b/2

Is the behavior of ember data changed in new version? How can I combine the requests to 1 request?

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour changed in Ember Data beta-9 to be opt-in. 
You can activate it by setting the `coalesceFindRequests` property of your adapter.

```
   DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
     coalesceFindRequests: true
   });
```

A more detailed description can be found in the offical blog entry for beta-9:
http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/08/18/ember-data-1-0-beta-9-released.html#toc_coalescing-find-requests

Comment: It really works, thanks. But why the ember do this? If we have each helper, that will cause thousands request.